# Existence of Schur's Decomposition & Cayley Hamilton Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I studied the definitions of Schur's Decomposition, Cayley Hamilton Theorem and Characteristic polynomial from the book [Horn & Johnson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521548233). For every definition and proof they have used a square matrix $A \in M_n$ where $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is abbreviated as $M_n$.

My question is this - from the fundamental theorem of algebra and in the links provided [here in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field) I will always get $n$ roots and hence can prove the Schur's Decomposition from which I can go to the Cayley Hamilton Theorem. However, in the matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ where $\mathbb{R}$ is the real field and not algebraically closed, does the above statements hold true also. If so how do I go about proving it ?

I saw a very similar question [here at math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245659/conditions-for-schur-decomposition-and-its-generalization), but it confused me more.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you mean the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: yes sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

1. As you have noted, $\mathbb R$ is not algebraically closed. Therefore real matrices don't always have Schur decomposition over $\mathbb R$. There is, however, an analogous decomposition over $\mathbb R$ that turns a matrix into a block-upper triangular form, in which every diagonal block is either a trivial block (i.e. a real scalar) or a $2\times2$ block $\pmatrix{a&-b\\ b&a}$ that represents a conjugate pair of nonreal eigenvalues $a+bi$. You may read Horn & Johnson about that.
2. Using that analogous decomposition, you may prove Cayley-Hamilton pretty much like you do in the complex case. Note that, as the aforementioned $2\times2$ block lumps together a conjugate pair of eigenvalues, it is no longer annihilated by a single linear factor $x-\lambda$ but by the product of a pair of linear factors $(x-a-bi)(x-a+bi)$.
3. There is, however, no need to consider a decomposition over $\mathbb R$ in the first place. We are talking about the same polynomial over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$. If $p(A)=0$ over $\mathbb C$, we must have $p(A)=0$ over $\mathbb R$, so it suffices to consider the complex field only.
4. To prove Cayley-Hamilton theorem over $\mathbb C$, it's actually easier to observe that the theorem is trivial for diagonalisable matrices and diagonalisable matrices are dense in $M_n(\mathbb C)$. Hence, by continuity, the theorem holds for every complex square matrix.
5. In general, suppose you want to prove an algebraic identity of the form  $f(a_1,\ldots,a_k)=g(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ for every $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$ taken from a commutative ring $R$, where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials with integer coefficients (here "integer" means a finite sum of zeros, 1s or -1s; it doesn't matter if the ring has finite characteristic). If you can prove that the same form of identity holds when $R$ is replaced by a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb C$, the identity will automagically becomes true for every commutative ring.
6. If you'd like to go more abstract, you may also prove that $f(X_1,\ldots,X_k)=g(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ directly for $f,g\in\mathbb Z[X_1,\ldots,X_k]$, where $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ denote $k$ different indeterminates. This and the idea in (5) are collectively called **the method of universal identities**. See, e.g. the expository paper [*Universal identities*](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/univid.pdf) written by Keith Conrad. The proof of Cayley-Hamilton theorem mentioned in (4) using diagonalisable matrices, for instance, has a more elegant counterpart in this setting. See the highest voted comment in [this answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39024) (the proof is in the comment, not in the answer) and [this answer on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/313284).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you clarify point 3 - I mean in point 3, what are the roots of the equation $p(A)=0$ when defined over $R$ ? I surely do not have $n$ roots all the time ?

Comment: @roni Of course you don't have a full set of eigenvalues all the time, but the statement of Cayley-Hamilton theorem does not require the existence of eigenvalues. It's all about *characteristic polynomial*, that is always defined (by $p(x)=\det(xI-A)$) regardless of the field.

Comment: Thanks! could you please explain what do you mean by diagonalisable matrices are dense in $M_n(C)$?

Comment: @roni It means the closure of all diagonalisable matrices is the whole matrix space, i.e. every $A$ is the limit of a sequence of diagonalisable matrices. By a change of basis, suppose $A$ is triangular. Then $A_t=A+\operatorname{diag}(t,t^2,t^3,\ldots,t^n)$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues when $t>0$ is sufficiently small. Hence $A_t$ is diagonalisable for all small $t>0$. Consequently, $A$ is the limit point of a sequence of diagonalisble matrices.